# How to make grabbing lists dynamic?

Tags: c#

So what I'm trying to do is make my code dynamic. My if statement works great because it iterates through the Lists one at a time on readline. But my issue is that I'm unsure how to make this dynamic. I don't want to have to repeat the if statement for every list that I make. How can I rearrange/set it up so that the program compares the readline input to any of the lists and if it matches a list then use that list in the foreach loop and writeline area?

I've only tried repeating myself which isn't a good practice and I can't find a way to make a list of lists that can be compared to the readline input.

```
Start:
    List<string> food = new List<string> { "banana", "apple", "steak", "chicken" };
    List<string> languages = new List<string> { "english", "greek", "spanish", "russian" };
    List<string> tech = new List<string> { "facebook", "apple", "google", "samsung" };
    List<string> colors = new List<string> { "blue", "green", "yellow", "red" };

    Console.WriteLine("Please choose a category: food, languages, tech, or colors.");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "food")
    {
        foreach (string foods in food)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(foods);
        }
    }

    goto Start;
```

What I'm expecting is that the app should function like it already is however the IF statement should be dynamic in grabbing whichever list matches the readline input and adjusting the statement accordingly to iterate through that list.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Guarav Mathur and D Stanley, I used pieces of both of your answers and it works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference variable names dynamically. How about a different approach, where you store the lists in a keyed dictionary:

```
List food = new List { "banana", "apple", "steak", "chicken" }; 
List languages = new List { "english", "greek", "spanish", "russian" }; 
List tech = new List { "facebook", "apple", "google", "samsung" }; 
List colors = new List { "blue", "green", "yellow", "red" };

var lists = new Dictionary<String, List<String>> {
    {"food", food },
    {"languages", languages },
    {"tech", tech },
    {"colors", colors },
};

Console.WriteLine("Please choose a category: food, languages, tech, or colors.");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (lists.ContainsKey(input))
{
    foreach (string item in lists[input])
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for your program -

```
List<string> food = new List<string> { "banana", "apple", "steak", "chicken" };
List<string> languages = new List<string> { "english", "greek", "spanish", "russian" };
List<string> tech = new List<string> { "facebook", "apple", "google", "samsung" };
List<string> colors = new List<string> { "blue", "green", "yellow", "red" };

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose a category: food, languages, tech, or colors.");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "food")
        ProcessList(food);
    else if (input == "languages")
        ProcessList(languages);
    else if (input == "tech")
        ProcessList(tech);
    else if (input == "colors")
        ProcessList(colors);
    else
        break;
}
```

And the function -

```
    private void ProcessList(List<string> list)
    {
        foreach (string item in list)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

I have removed `goto` as it is not recommended. You can achieve similar functionality using `while(true)` and providing a `break` statement to exit the program. In this case if a user enters anything except suggest options the program will exit. You can modify `if else` statements to according to your need.

Also I have changed `List` with generic `List<string>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Dictionary where the "value" is your existing list of strings and the the "key" is the list name.

The you could do something like

`var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();`

Then populate with your data. Then:

```
var list = myDictionary[input];
foreach (string s in list)
{
 Console.ReadLine();
 Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with that works really well and uses good practices! Thanks Gaurav Mathur and D Stanley!

```
 List<string> food = new List<string> { "banana", "apple", "steak", "chicken" };
        List<string> languages = new List<string> { "english", "greek", "spanish", "russian" };
        List<string> tech = new List<string> { "facebook", "apple", "google", "samsung" };
        List<string> colors = new List<string> { "blue", "green", "yellow", "red" };

        var lists = new Dictionary<String, List<String>> {
            {"food", food },
            {"languages", languages },
            {"tech", tech },
            {"colors", colors },
        };

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose a category: food, languages, tech, or colors.");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (lists.ContainsKey(input))
            {
                foreach (string item in lists[input])
                {
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```